# Vue App service works locally but not in Apache server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, vue.js

I have Vue App that when I do `npm run wc`
it works good on localhost; but when I put it on the server there is this error:

```
Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-app> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

What do I need to do to resolve the error?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you put some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to package.json file:

```
"service": "vue-cli-service build --target lib"‏
```

[image]

and the following commands should be run:

npm run build

npm run service